# Caption in table breaks into two lines

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, tabularx

I have a table in Latex but its caption breaks midway and spans two rows because of the two-sided paper format. It looks like this.

[image]

This is the code of the table.

`\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l| }
\hline
Model & Optimizer & Embedding & LR & RC & Dimension & Rounds & Depth & Num Kernels & Dropout\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Logistic Regression} & Adam & Static &  &  & & & & & \\
 & SGD & Dynamic &  &  & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Hyperparameter values of all the models after cross validation}
\label{table_1}
\end{table}`

I want the caption to span the complete row. What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following text shows that the end of line is reached. The caption title is longer than one line, thus it is broken across two lines. The table (`tabular`) cannot be broken across lines and very likely causes a massive overfull `\hbox` warning.

The line width is quite small, thus I suspect two-column mode. Then the star form `table*` gives a table object spanning the whole text width.

BTW, using `\centering` in environment `table` or `table*` instead of environment `center` avoids the additional vertical space of environment `center`.

Comment: I don't understand as I am new to Latex. What should be done to avoid this?

Comment: @Hellboy Try replacing `table` with `table*`. The question does not show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Thus, I cannot say, whether my guesses (e.g. two column mode) are correct.

Comment: Replacing table to table* removes the problem but moves the table to the end of the document on the next page. I want the table to be at this position.

Comment: @Hellboy See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/16967) or as [article](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/tb111mitt-float.pdf).